# Given a range of values 1 though n, what is the most efficent way to split that list into m "nearly equal" sub-ranges?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, partitioning

For example, if I have a range of numbers from 1 to 27, and I want to split that range into 7 sub-ranges, an answer given n=27, m = 7 (using tuples to denote start/end ranges) might be:

[(1,4),(5,8),(9,12),(13,16),(17,20),(21,24),(25,27)]

I've started to try and come up with some good heuristics (based on the size of a mod b) to come up with a decent answer each time (i.e. the difference between the largest sub-range and the smallest sub-range is less than some value), but surely this has been implemented in Haskell somewhere before.

My use case is finding a set of ranges for parallel processing of enumerations in a given range, so I want to find the ranges so that all parallel processes finish their processing at approximately the same time.

Comment: 27 `div` 7 is 3, 27 `mod` 7 is 6. So you will have 6 ranges of length 3+1, and 7-6 ranges of length 3.

Comment: 27=6*4+3 is not a good example; the problem is seen clearer for 25=6*4+1= 2*3+4*4+3, or 9=2*4+1=3+3+3.

Comment: 25=3*3+4*4. You only ever need two size of ranges, differing by one.

Comment: Sounds like a relative of Brezenham's Algorithm would work: accumulate a term for the error so far, and bump the range by one periodically when the error gets too high.

Comment: Accumulating the error is a good way if you want to spread the intervals evenly. And its easy abd accurate with rational numbers.

Comment: @augustss by your algorithm, splitting 27 in 7 gives `27/7=3, 27%7=6 => 6*4+(7-6)*3`, so splitting 25 into 6 nearly-equal ranges gives `25/6=4, 25%6=1 => 1*5+(6-1)*4`, which is just as good. I was a bit confused there, thought about a different problem (splitting into nearly-equaled portions, given a maximal size).